# UDF function fails in Spark 3.3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, user-defined-functions, spark3

I have an application developed with Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.4 where and UDF is applied to a streaming dataframe to add a new column. Due to other library requirements, I have moved the application to Scala 2.12 and Spark 3.3 but now the code fails when the UDF is applied to the steaming dataframe with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.app.Processor
```

A simplified version of my UDF looks like

```scala
val service = (data:String) => {

    if (data != null) {
        if (data == "1") {
            val body = "One"
        } else {
            val body = "Two"
        }
    } else { 
        val body = "null found"
    }

    body
}
```

The UDF is registered

```scala
val serviceUDF = spark.udf.register("server", service)
```

And applied to a readStream object consuming a Kafka topic

```scala
var stream = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
    .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
    .load()
    .select(col("value").cast(StringType), col("timestamp"))

val ds = stream
    .withColumn("test", serviceUDF(col("value")))
```

This job is launched with spark3-submit

```bash
spark3-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties" \
    --files conf/log4j.properties \
    --class com.app.Processor \
    --jars target/scala-2.12/app_2.12-1.0.jar
```

And this is the returned error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (betsabe6 executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.app.Processor$
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1274)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2222)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:380)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.app.Processor$
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1274)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2222)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Is it possible that something needs to be changed in the UDF in order to work properly on a streaming dataframe in Spark 3.3? I haven't found anything so far.

The same code works fine with Spark 2.4 and Scala 2.11, the only changes are spark3-submit instead of spark-submit and the build.sbt file used to compile the jar, where I call Spark/Scala specific versions